# How to adjust the width of cells in a column according to the size of the header?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tables, tabularx

The following code comes from a solution to the question ([How to make tables with a small cell to the right inside another large cell?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/583575/155047)), but if I add a header with text longer than what is established the table is distorted, I would like the width of the columns to fit the content of the table header.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix, fit}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
        row 1/.style={nodes={draw=none}},
        mmat/.style={matrix of math nodes,nodes in empty cells,
        row sep=-\pgflinewidth,column sep=-\pgflinewidth,
        nodes={minimum width=5.5em,minimum height=3.5em, draw,anchor=center, text depth=0.25ex,text height=0.8em}},
        inlay/.style={label={[draw,thin,anchor=north east,minimum width=0em, minimum height=0em,inner sep=1.4pt]north east:#1}}]
        
        \matrix[mmat] (mat){
        &   &   &   &\\
        \mbox{long text one}
            &  \mbox{long text two} 
                &2 
                    &3 
                        &4 
                            &5 
                                &Oferta \\           
        1
            &  |[inlay=4]|11
                & |[inlay=2]|  22  
                    & |[inlay=5]|33    
                        & |[inlay=5]| 44     
                            & |[inlay=1]|55  
                                &100 \\
        }; 
        \node[yshift=-1mm, fit=(mat-1-3)(mat-1-5)]{Destino};
        
            \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Result]

Comment: I have made two changes -- expand the node width `nodes={minimum width=6em,` -- and -- `\usepackage{makecell}` to break the long text into multi line of choice -- read the documentation for many more options available at -- http://mirrors.ibiblio.org/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/makecell/makecell.pdf

Answer (score 1):

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath, makecell}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix, fit}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
        row 1/.style={nodes={draw=none}},
        mmat/.style={matrix of math nodes,nodes in empty cells,
            row sep=-\pgflinewidth,column sep=-\pgflinewidth,
            nodes={minimum width=6em,minimum height=3.5em, draw,anchor=center, text depth=0.25ex,text height=0.8em}},
        inlay/.style={label={[draw,thin,anchor=north east,minimum width=0em, minimum height=0em,inner sep=1.4pt]north east:#1}}]
        
        \matrix[mmat] (mat){
            &   &   &   &\\
            \makecell[l]{long \\text\\ one}
            &  \makecell[c]{long\ text\\ one}
            &2 
            &3 
            &4 
            &5 
            &Oferta \\           
            1
            &  |[inlay=4]|11
            & |[inlay=2]|  22  
            & |[inlay=5]|33    
            & |[inlay=5]| 44     
            & |[inlay=1]|55  
            &100 \\
        }; 
        \node[yshift=-1mm, fit=(mat-1-3)(mat-1-5)]{Destino};
        
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

In original code `long text one` is inside a `\makebox` which is unbreakable. `node`s are something similar to a `parbox` and can include multiline text, but a `text width` is needed for that. This is what is shown in following code. `text width` in main nodes, also fixes `text width` in `inlay` ones, so a new `text width` has been fixed there.

Also the `matrix of math nodes` has been changed to `matrix of nodes` and the table title has been included as a `label` in third column. This way first row can be eliminated.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix, fit}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
%        row 1/.style={nodes={draw=none}},
        mmat/.style={matrix of nodes,nodes in empty cells,
        row sep=-\pgflinewidth,column sep=-\pgflinewidth,
        nodes={minimum width=5.5em, minimum height=3.5em, draw, anchor=center, text width=4.5em, align=center}},
        inlay/.style={label={[draw, thin, anchor=north east, minimum width=0em, minimum height=0em, inner sep=1.4pt, text width=2em]north east:#1}}]
        
        \matrix[mmat] (mat){
%        &   &   &   &\\
        long text one
            & long text two
                &2 
                    &|[label=Destino]|3 
                        &4 
                            &5 
                                &Oferta \\           
        1
            &  |[inlay=4]|11
                & |[inlay=2]|  22  
                    & |[inlay=5]|33    
                        & |[inlay=5]| 44     
                            & |[inlay=1]|55  
                                &100 \\
        }; 
%        \node[yshift=-1mm, fit=(mat-1-3)(mat-1-5)]{Destino};
        
            \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]